# Reuse fields for many calculations with DataFrames.transform in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to use one line or one execution to create many fields.

```
using DataFrames;
df=DataFrame(a=[1,2,3], b=[4,5,6])

transform(df,[:a,:b ]=>ByRow((x,y)-> x*y/5) => :c )

transform(df,[:a,:b ]=>ByRow((x,y)-> x/y*6) => :d )
```

But I want:

```
transform(df,[:a,:b ].=>[ByRow((x,y)->x*y/5) , ByRow((x,y)-> x/y*6)] .=> [:c,:d])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want: `transform(df,[:a,:b ]=>ByRow((x,y)-> (x*y/5, x/y*6)) => [:c,:d] )`

```
julia> transform(df,[:a,:b ]=>ByRow((x,y)-> (x*y/5, x/y*6)) => [:c,:d] )
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c        d       
     │ Int64  Int64  Float64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      4      0.8      1.5
   2 │     2      5      2.0      2.4
   3 │     3      6      3.6      3.0
```

Comment: Here??: transform(df,[:a,:b ]=>((x,y) -> (x.*y./5 , x./y.*6) )=> [:c,:d] )